# 403 response overlaps the handling of the other exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've implemented the Spring Security authentication in my Spring application, following the next configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

As you can see, the only endpoints the user can access without an authentication token are the ones which start with `/auth` (this are, the login endpoint and the register endpoint).

The problem is, even when the user makes a mistake which is not involved with the authentication, the application returns a 403 forbidden status.
For example, when the user tries to access to an non-existent endpoint, instead of returning a 404 NOT FOUND, it also returns a 403 FORBIDDEN exception. Or, when there is a problem in the code, instead of returning a 500 INTERNAL SERVER error, it returns a 403 again.

This only happens with the endpoints which requieres authentication (not with the `auth/**` ones).
And, when I replace `.authenticated()` with `.permitAll()` like this:

```java
.anyRequest().permitAll()
```

All the error handlers starts working properly again (returns 404, 500, etc.).

What have I to do to get the 403 status working only with the authentication errors?